# Creating a loop that generates new DatagramSockets?

Tags: java, variables, loops

Hi I want to loop through a list of `n` amount of ports I have and create a DatagramSocket for each of them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < portList.size(); i++) {
    DatagramSocket socket[i] = new DatagramSocket();
    socket[i].connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portList.get(i));
}
```

I know i'm not supposed to use `socket[i]` . It's only to express what I mean, the above will generate:

```
DatagramSocket socket1 = new DatagramSocket();
socket1.connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2000);

DatagramSocket socket2 = new DatagramSocket();
socket2.connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2001);

DatagramSocket socket3 = new DatagramSocket();
socket3.connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2002);

DatagramSocket socket4 = new DatagramSocket();
socket4.connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2003);
```

I'm not so good at Java so this is probably a silly question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Russell's answer is pretty good. Just to sum it up, here's what I would write:

```
//get local host
InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

//make a List to hold the sockets
//we know how many there will be so use that capacity
List<DatagramSocket> datagramSockets =
        new ArrayList<DatagramSocket>(portList.size());

//for each port,
for (Integer port : portList) {
    //instantiate a new socket
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    //add it to the list
    datagramSockets.add(datagramSocket);
    //connect it using the port
    datagramSocket.connect(localHost, port);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, however `datagramSocket.connect(localHost, port);` line is giving me an error...

Comment: What's the error? Is it a compile or runtime error? I just took that call from your original example - looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) it should compile.

Comment: Make sure everything is properly imported is all I can say.

Comment: found the error: I used the wrong data type for `port` :( thanks, I like this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use maybe, an `ArrayList` to store your sockets first:

```
ArrayList<DatagramSocket> socketList = new ArrayList<DatagramSocket>();
socketList.add(new DatagramSocket());
socketList.add(new DatagramSocket());
socketList.add(new DatagramSocket());
socketList.add(new DatagramSocket());
```

then loop through the `socketList`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < portList.size(); i++) {
    socketList.get(i).connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portList.get(i));
}
```

This is assuming that you have the **same number** of ports and added `DatagramSocket`s in your `socketList`. Otherwise, it will throw a `NullPointer` somewhere in the loop.

**UPDATE**

Solution from **user1753100**:

```
ArrayList<DatagramSocket> socketList = new ArrayList<DatagramSocket>();
for (int j = 0; j < portList.size(); j++) {
    socketList.add(new DatagramSocket());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Is this the best practice in Java for creating new variables (not just Datagrams) via iteration?

Comment: Hmm, I would instantiate and add the `DatagramSocket`s in a loop as well. Good answer though +1!

Comment: @user1753100 it depends actually. If you need to set unique properties *before* you add them in the list, you need to instantiate them first, then set the property *before* adding.

Comment: @user1753100 or you can do something like `socketList.add(new DatagramSocket().setSomeProperty("some value"));`. But I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @RussellGutierrez - I think you're confused. Only the references to the instances are added to the list. You can just as well set properties on them afterward. About your second comment - `setSomeProperty` would need to return `DatagramSocket` for that to work, but that pattern shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @PaulBellora Oh yes. But what I meant was if you *really* need to set the property before adding. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also is it possible to combine your solution into one loop? e.g. `socketList.add` and then `socketList.conect` wrapped inside a loop?

Comment: Im not really sure. You should try it out yourself: `for(int i = 0; i < portList.size(); i++) {
    socketList.add(new DatagramSocket().connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portList.get(i)));
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<DatagramSocket> socketList = new ArrayList<DatagramSocket>();

for(int i=0;i<portList.size();i++)

 {
   socketList.add(new DatagramSocket().connect(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: `connect` returns `void` though.

Comment: @PaulBellora Thnx..did not notice it